# Analyzing time complexity of solution in tutorial

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis

Could someone explain time complexity of solution of in this [tutorial](https://cp-algorithms.com/combinatorics/inclusion-exclusion.html#toc-tgt-13)?

I'm having hard time figuring out, how asymptotic bounds for first solution is $O(3^k k)$.

What I figured so far is, for computing $f(Y)$, we would require $O(\lvert Y\rvert)$ steps and for fixed set $X$ (such that $\lvert X\rvert=k$), we would have $2^{n-k}$ number of $Y$ sets that would contain set $X$. And there would be ${n \choose k}$ such $X$ sets.

So total steps should be $${n \choose k } {\sum_{r=0}^{n-k} {n-k \choose r} ({k+r})} \leq {n \choose k} n  2^{n-k}$$

But is this value tightly bounded by $3^k k$?

Answer (score 1):

Let me focus on the following question:

> Is $3^nn$ a tight bound on $\binom{n}{k}n2^{n-k}$?

First, let us see that this is a valid bound. This follows from the binomial theorem:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} n 2^{n-k} = 3^nn.
$$

Since there are $n+1$ summands in the expression, we deduce that
$$
\max_{0 \leq k \leq n} \binom{n}{k} n 2^{n-k} \ge \frac{3^nn}{n+1}.
$$
Using Stirling's formula, we find out that
$$
\max_{0 \leq k \leq n} \binom{n}{k} n 2^{n-k} = \Theta(3^n\sqrt{n}).
$$
This is a tighter bound.

Comment: First of all thanks for your time. I don't know if my analysis is even correct or not. But asymptotic of solution was $(k3^k)$, it does not include $n$ at all. Input variables are $n$ and $k$ and $k \leq n$.